# How to set pacing time separately for each script in Loadtest (VSTS)

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I want to know how to set pacing time separately for each script in Loadtest(VSTS)

Requirement is:

Test Run Duration one hour

[image]

Test type : Based on the number of virtual users
Test Distribution : Is as per weightage

So pls help me **how can I achieve the above mentioned pacing time in one scenario of Load test.**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test pacing and choice of test to run next is set in the scenario. You can use multiple scenarios in a load test to give different load patterns to different (groups of) tests.

A common use of two scenarios is for testing a web site used by both customers and managers. One scenario simulates a large number of customers doing customer activities, another scenario simulates a small number of managers doing their activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the thinktime of last request in each script.